# PHP code adding quotes and breaking flow

Tags: php

I have an embedded code that adds a quotation mark before the end of a loop and as a result, the code from that point on is regarded as HTML, displayed on the page as very ugly text and ignored by the PHP interpreter. I tried storing the while condition in a variable but it does me no good. I also transferred the code to another document and the behavior was exactly the same. My code is attached below

```
<?php
$title = $_GET['sermon_title'];
$preacher = $_GET['preacher'];
$main = $_GET['sermon_body'];

$sermon_url = explode(" ", $title);
$new_string = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($sermon_url); $i++) {
if (strlen($sermon_url[$i])>3) {
$new_string[] = $sermon_url[$i];
}
}
$sermon_url = "/sermons/" . implode("-", $new_string);

if (isset($title && $preacher && $main)) {
fwrite(fopen("/sermons/" . $sermons_url . "/index.html", "x"),     file_get_contents("/sermons/sermon_template.html"));
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user",  "pass1", "general_db");
$q = "INSERT INTO sermons_table VALUES(" . $title . ", " . $sermon_url . ", " . $preacher . ")";
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            die("Sermons we not added because " . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: It's not entering PHP because the starting PHP tag is broken. `<?php` would enter PHP; while `<!--?php` isn't valid - it's a HTML comment (because of the leading `<!--`. Can you show the code prior to this, the lines before `$title = $_GET['sermon_title'];`?

Comment: There's nothing before it, just the php opening tag

Comment: Apparently there is *something*, because according to your image the PHP tag gets commented out as a HTML-comment. What about this code you spoke of, that added a quotation mark before the end of a loop?

Comment: That is my browser's developer tab gotten through Ctrl + I on chrome. By default it hides PHP codes. That entire code should be hidden but instead it stops at some point and regards the rest as HTML. Test your PHP codes in that developer tab, youl'll see they are commented out to avoid showing up in your document

Comment: *Ctrl + Shift + I @Qirel

Comment: "*By default it hides PHP codes*" that's because the PHP is interpreted before it's ever sent to the browser. You seem to have some funky function that comments out that opening PHP tag, perhaps you should enable error-reporting (if you can) [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) -- also, did you check your apache logs?

Comment: Nah! I'm running the script from my local file system. Try copying this my current code onto your computer and see what happens. Ignore the picture I uploaded and unit test. Then probably, check a php code on your browser's developer tab or this my present script: you'll see it was commented out.

Comment: I just did (and I could tell from the code already provided) that it is not commented out. There has to be *something* that changes that `<?php` tag into a HTML comment, but from the code-snippet you provided, there is nothing.

Comment: @Qirel baboizk I've removed the confusing image. You can focus on the code I posted now. Forget about hidden comments and all that; I was just trying to make things clearer but that seemed to be my undoing. Please focus on the code I posted now thanks

Comment: I did, and I'm telling you - the code seems fine, but you should enable error-reporting (as previously suggested), and let PHP tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @Qirel I'm mentioning you on the chat thread -_-

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a missclick, I didn't think you got to see it before I deleted the comment :P Got a link, and I'll hop over.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your problem ...why do you comment PHP code with HTML comments?

Try to write the code like

```
 <?php 
 /* here is my 
 commented code */ 


 here is my uncommented code 
?>
```

This way the quotation mark should be in front of the `<?php` opening tag.. I guess.

As a side note... if that is the whole code you are using for that page, the uncommented part of that code will never work, as it is.

Comment: I'm not the one adding the comments bro nor am I hiding the code. PHP code is hidden by default in HTML documents. Open a random document on your browser containing php and click CTRL SHIFT I, you'll see that php code is commented out using html tags so it doesn't appear in your docs

Comment: Your code, if the comments are removed, is perfectly fine. As Qirel  said, you should enable error reporting and see why your opening PHP tag get's commented.